# What are the best 2D animation formats that could be used for android games

Tags: java, android, animation, 2d

I know that its possible to use a sequence of images in a sprite, however, I would like to have something more decent, frame rate dependent, similar to some 3D available formates.

I would prefer something, vector based, similar to Flash, if any.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [gamedev article](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/what-external-2d-animation-formats-can-i-use-in-android). Maybe it's better to move the question there ...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some great results from SVG, which is a standard format that's supported by programs like Adobe Illustrator. http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ is an SVG parser/renderer for Android. I haven't tried it myself but it looks promising.